# rails w/ legacy database that has id NOT as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to hook up a rails 3 app to a legacy mysql database. One of the tables has only two columns: "name" and "id". "name" is the primary key (lucking for me).

I've set the primary key using:

set_primary_key :name

BUT whenever I retrieve the record, it assigns the value of name to both the id and name attributes.

I thought about creating a mysql view, but i need to be able to set id, not just read the value. i tried using alias_attribute to no avail.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can make updatable views in mysql at least, so that might be an option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html